# To add an external library(not jar) in Android Studio project do i need to add other libraries(.jar ones) that first one is referencing before hand?

Tags: android, jar, libraries

I have been strucked in this, since long, and the other methods seems not to work, getting the "default" configuration error, 
if someone has the answer then please give me a link.

Comment: Hi swarup , As per my understanding from your question you are trying to add a non jar module to your App , you can either create a new module or import an existing module to your studio . If you have any other dependencies you can add it in your build.gradle or add it as jar . Clean build your project . Hopefully this helps

Comment: I want to add some external library, like those on github. https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidImageSlider, this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has already been mentioned in the Git find the link and add the gradle dependencies mentioned at - https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidImageSlider/blob/master/README.md .